# Angular loading bar error

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error with angular loading bar

```
            var _responseError = function (rejection) {
            $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
            var authService = $injector.get('authService');

            if (rejection.status === 401 && authData && authData.isActive == 'true') {
                var deferred = $q.defer(); // defer until we can re-request a new token
                var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + authData.refreshToken + "&client_id=" + authData.clientId;
                var baseAddress = $injector.get('baseAddress');
                var dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";

                // Get a new token... (cannot inject $http directly as will cause a circular ref)
                $injector.get("$http")
                    .post(baseAddress + 'login', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
                    .then(function (loginResponse) {
                        if (loginResponse.data) {
                            localStorageService.set('authorizationData',
                             {
                                 token: loginResponse.data.access_token,
                                 tokenExpire: loginResponse.data['.expires'],
                                 refreshToken: loginResponse.data.refresh_token,
                                 refreshTokenExpire: loginResponse.data.refreshTokenExpire,
                                 userName: authData.userName,
                                 roleName: loginResponse.data.roleName,
                                 isUserAdmin: loginResponse.data.isUserAdmin,
                                 clientId: 'Self',
                                 isActive: loginResponse.data.isActive
                             });
                            // now let's retry the original request 
                            $injector.get("$http")(rejection.config).then(function (response) {
                                // we have a successful response - resolve it using deferred
                                deferred.resolve(response);
                            }, function (response) {
                                deferred.reject(); // something went wrong
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            deferred.reject(); // login call didn't give us data
                        }
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        // token retry failed, redirect so user can login again
                        deferred.reject(rejection);
                        if (!authInterceptorServiceFactory.isPopup) {
                            authInterceptorServiceFactory.isPopup = true;
                            var hr = moment.utc(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(new Date(authData.refreshTokenExpire)))).format("H");
                            var strHr = hr == 1 ? ' hour' : ' hours';

                            var min = moment.utc(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(new Date(authData.refreshTokenExpire)))).format("m");
                            if (min == 0) {
                                min = 1;
                            }

                            var strMin = min == 1 ? ' minute' : ' minutes';

                            var loginInfo = {
                                userName: authData.userName,
                                password: '',
                                expiryTime: moment.utc(moment(new Date()).diff(moment(new Date(authData.refreshTokenExpire)))).format("HH:mm:ss")
                            };

                            var ngDialog = $injector.get('ngDialog');
                            ngDialog.openConfirm({
                                template: '/app/account/loginDialog.html',
                                className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                                controller: 'loginDialogController',
                                showClose: false,
                                data: loginInfo
                            }).then(function (value) {
                                authInterceptorServiceFactory.isPopup = false;
                                //only refresh if GET request was executed
                                if (rejection.config.method == "GET")
                                    $window.location.reload();
                            }, function (reason) {
                                authInterceptorServiceFactory.isPopup = false;
                                // User has decided to logout from login modal so clear all
                                //authentication information, reject the request and redirect to login
                                blockUI.stop();
                                authService.logOut();
                                $location.path('/login');
                                return;
                            });
                        }
                    });

                return deferred.promise; // return the deferred promise
            }
            else if ((rejection.status === 401 && !authData) || (rejection.status === 401 && authData.isActive == 'false')) {

                    blockUI.stop();
                    authService.logOut();
                    $location.path('/login');
            }
            else if (rejection.status === 403) {
                // Unauthorized =  Access Forbidden 403 
                // Before navigating away, we need to clear the change tracker changes, otherwise the changes alert will appear.
                blockUI.stop();
                changeTrackerService.clearAllScopeChanges();
                $location.path('/unauthorized');

            }
            return $q.reject(rejection); // **I am getting error here** 
        }
```

and the error is

TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at error (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular-block-ui.js?v=1.3:176:26)
    at https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:109:276
    at h.c.$get.h.$eval (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:123:139)
    at h.c.$get.h.$digest (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:120:220)
    at h.c.$get.h.$apply (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:123:406)
    at p (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:80:284)
    at J (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:84:338)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:85:367) undefined(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:101b.$get @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:75(anonymous function) @ angular-block-ui.js?v=1.3:19(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:109c.$get.h.$eval @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:123c.$get.h.$digest @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:120c.$get.h.$apply @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:123p @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:80J @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:84t.onload @ angular.min.js?v=1.3:85

angular.min.js?v=1.3:101 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ignoreLoadingBar' of undefined
    at config.responseError (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/loading-bar.js?v=1.3:129:32)
    at https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:109:276
    at h.c.$get.h.$eval (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:123:139)
    at h.c.$get.h.$digest (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:120:220)
    at h.c.$get.h.$apply (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:123:406)
    at p (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:80:284)
    at J (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:84:338)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (https://localhost:44303/Scripts/angular.min.js?v=1.3:85:367) undefined

Comment: nobody can help you until there is a working copy of it, and your code sits on your localhost. Moreover, modify the libraries to un-minified versions, and then post the error you're facing. That would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't Use Min For Development

The first thing you need to do in you index page is change the version of Angular you are using.

**From**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**To**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
```

Using min is great from production because its smaller and there for faster to interoperate but it has very misleading errors.

Once you have switched to the full Angular post your new error in an edit and I'll add to this answer.